# Summation giving incorrect value (I think) in Mathematica

Tags: calculus, summation, mathematica

I have the problem $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{x=2}^4 \dfrac{1}{x^2}$. I know the answer to this problem should be $\dfrac{61}{144}$. When I type the problem into Wolfram Mathematica, I get the answer $\dfrac{205}{144}$.

Is there something wrong with my syntax? I'm new to Mathematica:

```
x = 2
Sum[(1/x^2), {x, 4}]
```

Comment: It must be WA is high again...Don't worry, it's not the first/second/third/.... bug that's been found in WA

Comment: You want Sum[(1/x^2), {x, 2, 4}]. The initial x=2 does nothing for the sum

Comment: You mean... *Mathematica* has a bug!? Lord help us all!

Comment: I'm no Mathematica groupie. But to be clear, this isn't a bug. It's a user syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mathematica, the bound variable in `Sum` starts at 1 when the second argument is in the form `{x,n}`. It is also defined locally, so setting its value outside changes nothing. To make it start from 2, use `{x,2,4}` as the second argument. But this is really a question for Mathematica Stack Exchange.

Comment: Ah! I see that now. Thanks. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html this should've answered my question, but I had some difficulty reading it, honestly. I for some reason can't flag it for Mathematica migration now, so if you'd like to (and can), I would understand.

Comment: @JakenHerman Mathematica help pages do require learning the format (and sometimes the information is in weird places: look up the `FourierParameters` command, for example, and you'll discover that the information you actually want is in the individual transform articles. On the other hand, they're much easier to read than most help pages, and tend to have tons of examples.